# Making PostGIS extension persist in the search_path of a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, extensions, schema

## Context

I have a script to set up a [PostgreSQL](https://postgis.net/) database along with the [postgis](https://postgis.net/) extension which I decided to install in an other schema than `public`, namely, the `postgis` schema. In my script, this schema is then set in the search path as explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354528/65370);

```
SET search_path TO "$user", postgis, topology, public;
```

After having successfully executed my creation script, I was totally surprised by this error while connected with the `user` role I defined (different than the `postgres` role) and using a PostGIS function to test it was correctly installed:

```
$ psql -U user -d my_database
psql (10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

my_database=# SELECT st_astext(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.0, 42.0),4326));
ERROR:  function st_makepoint(numeric, numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT st_astext(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.0, 42.0),4326));
                                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Then I checked for the `search_path`;

```
my_database=# show search_path;
        search_path        
---------------------------
 "$user", public, topology
(1 row)
```

Astonishing; PostGIS is no more here!

I have to enter the `SET` command again, manually, to make it come back:

```
$ psql -U user -d my_database
my_database=# SET search_path TO "$user", postgis, topology, public;
SET
my_database=# show search_path;
                 search_path                 
---------------------------------------------
 "$user", postgis, topology, public
(1 row)
```

But this doesn't persist across re-connections.

## Question

How to make it persistent?

#### Related questions and links

[Use PostGIS functions from an other schema (than public)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354523/use-postgis-functions-from-an-other-schema-than-public)

[PostGIS functions do not exist even when public is in the search path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278233/postgis-functions-do-not-exist-even-when-public-is-in-the-search-path)

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208393425-type-geometry-does-not-exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General rule

The PostGIS extension must be in the user `search_path` as explained here

## Detailed explanation

Using `SET search_path TO "$user", public, postgis, topology;` makes it immediately available while `ALTER ROLE` or `ALTER DATABASE` makes it available at the next session. But the latter commands make it persist through future connections.

Therefore, you would need e.g. to `ALTER` the `user` role with the following **in addition** to the immediate `SET` statement in your script if you want to use PostGIS in future sessions;

```
SET search_path TO "$user", postgis, topology, public;
ALTER ROLE user SET search_path TO "$user", postgis, topology, public;
```

### A little warning

The order the schemas are set in the `search_path` is important because tables will be searched according to this order!

#### Credits, for having put me on the right track

[With schema, function postgis_full_version() does not exist](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/with-schema-function-postgis-full-version-does-not-exist)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875610/permanently-set-postgresql-schema-path